# Javascript "for loop" variable pointer

Tags: javascript

I am sure I simply didn't have enough coffee yet to see clearly, and this seems trivial, however, I have a for loop that passes some functions in a jQuery plugin. var i is passed, and of course, passes the last value of i, instead of the value it was assigned when passing through.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 3 + 1; i++) {
    $('#div' + i).plugin({ // i returns correctly here
    onDelete: function () {
            alert("Deleting #" + i); // i returns 4 every time - last value of i
        }
    });
}
```

How do I "copy" i, so it is returned as I expect? I have a workaround, but I would love to know, so I can put my head in the sand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a well-known for loop problem. You have to wrap it in a closure each time:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++)(function(i) {
    $('#div' + i).plugin({
        onDelete: function() {
            alert("Deleting #" + i);
        }
    });
})(i);
```

Or you can use this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    $('#div' + i).plugin({
        onDelete: callback(i)
    });
};

function callback(i) {
    return function() {
        alert("Deleting #" + i);
    };
}
```

Comment: Sweet. I can't believe I didn't think of that. What does the post (i) do exactly?

Comment: @MichaelC.Gates It's called an [immediately-invoked function expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-construct-in-javascript) (or IIFE). The `(i)` part is calling the function with the argument `i`. You should consider using my last one as it is 
easier to understand.

Comment: I meant the very last line })(i);. Your link cleared it up for me. Thx again.

Comment: @MichaelC.Gates Yeah that was what I was referring to. I took out the for loop brackets and replaced it with one big IIFE.

Comment: @MichaelC.Gates Is there anything you still don't understand about it? I'd be happy to help.